# Angularjs typeahead show 'add' option if entered text not in list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I am using angular `typeahead` to list option from a web service.

I would like to provide an option to add new values if not returned from the web service.

I found an answer which adds the entered text to a local array and when the user submits the form it can be saved, but there is possibility for error in the entered text the wrong data might get added to the db.

So i want it to be a button or option in the list so that the entered text will be added only if the user clicks that option.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newData.category" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="category for category in getCategory($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)">
```

My expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a hidden input field and swap it with the other one if the user selects "Add new category"

To do this, start by adding "Add new category" as the last value in your categories array. Then in your onSelect function

```
$scope.onSelect = function(item) {
  // you existing code...
  if($scope.newData.category === "Add new category") {
    $scope.newData.category = ''; // set to empty string so the input box is empty
    $scope.showAddCategory = true;
  }
}
```

Then you can do this in your HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newData.category" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="category for category in getCategory($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)" ng-hide="showAddCategory">

<div ng-show="showAddCategory">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newData.category" class="form-conrol">
  <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

When the user selects "Add new category" it will hide the default input and then show a new one that does not have typeahead.

If you use this approach, you will probably want to have some way for them to go back to the categories list (i.e. change newData.catagory so the default input is visible again)

Note: I added a `div` wrapper and save `button` to the hidden input just because you will probably want something like that for your UI, but those are not necessary. You could put the `ng-show` directly on the `input`.

Comment: I have added the "Add new" option in my categories array. but since the entered text does not match "Add new" the option is not listed. is there any option to show "Add new" is no match is found

Comment: I don't understand, can you put your controller code into a snippet or something so I can take a look? Is your categories array an array of strings?

Comment: `var categories = ["Add new Category"];` its just an array of string. This gets updated with the values which i get from web service

Comment: Ok I understand, the "Add new" is not sppearing because the filter is filtering it out. You will need to create a custom filter that works just like the current filter, but allows for "Add new" to always appear (or have it appear when there are less than 3 results or something similar)

Comment: i am new to this can you help me with the filter?